# Swift Fill sections & rows in UiTableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, dictionary, cells

I am trying to fill in a table view from a dictionary data source and tried a lot to achieve desired result but lot of error, need help on this:

this is my test code in playground which almost gives me desired result, but when i try to do same thing in project nothing works:

I have marked my questions next to problem command line:

```
var sections = Dictionary<String, Array<String>>()

var mySId = ["s1","s2"]
var  m``Sdate = ["jun1", "jun2"]
var mEdate = ["jun2", "jun4"]


var mytotalArr = [String]()

var index = 0
for myId in myScId {

    mytotalArr.append(mSdate[index]) // transfer data to total array to group
    mytotalArr.append(mEdate[index]) // tarnsfer data to total array to group

    sections["\(myScId[index])"] = mytotalArr

    index++

}

println(sections["sch1"]!)  // "[jun1, jun1]"

// in project i do it like this  

in cellForRowAtIndexPath

var myarr =     sections[indexpath.section]
```

when i do same as above in project error message // Unresolved Identified indexPath

```
var mystring = sections["sch1"]!

println(mystring[1])  // "jun1"
```

Or Please suggest a way to achieve the result as below

```
Section header =     Sch1 ,
row1 = jun1      // mSdate ,
row2 = jun2      // mEdate

section header = Sch2 ,
row1 = jun2 ,
row2 = jun4
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this was not simple to figure out, but i managed using other Stack's.

Basically first you get the value from your first key in Dict, and that search for data witihin it.

little overkill on system and coding, but it works.